# I need help in Nested Cursors in SQL server

Tags: cursors

I need to use `Member` table, `Member_Account` table and `Class` table to calculate Monthly Fee of any member, i've created a procedure and nested cursors for this purpose, please help if anyone understands my problem

```
create procedure CalcFee(@Member_Id int)

as

Declare
@Class_Price decimal(18,2),
@Total decimal(18,2),
@Class_Id int;

Begin
Set @Class_Id=(Select Class_Id from Member_Account where Member_Id=@Member_Id);

Set @Class_Price=(Select Class_Price from Class where Class_Id=@Class_Id);

Set @Total= @Total + @Class_Price;

update Member set Monthly_Fee=@Total where Member_Id=@Member_Id;

end;



Declare firstcursor Cursor For

Select Member_Id from Member

declare

@Member_1 int;

Begin

Open firstcursor;

Fetch next from firstcursor Member_Id into @Member_1;

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0

Begin

Declare secondcursor Cursor For

Select Member_Id from Member_Account

declare

@Member_2 int;

Begin

Open secondcursor;

Fetch next from firstcursor Member_Id into @Member_2;

while select * from Member_Account where Member_Id=@Member_2

Begin

exec CalcFee @Member_Id = @Member_2;

Fetch next from firstcursor Member_Id into @Member_2;

end;

close secondcursor;

deallocate secondcursor;

end

Fetch next from firstcursor Member_Id into @Member_1;

end;

close firstcursor;

deallocate firstcursor;

end;
```

Comment: Better to just show us the table structures, example data and desired results so we don't have to reverse engineer your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need cursors for this at all. Whenever you think that you need to loop or treat members one row at a time, you need to step back and think about why you need to do that. SQL Server operates best on set-based logic, not row-by-row iteration. Here is a set-based update statement that updates all members at once, doesn't require any loops (never mind nested cursors), and I *think* does what you want (you didn't initialize `@Total` so currently that is always going to be `NULL` - perhaps you meant to initialize it as `0` or perhaps that comes from somewhere else that your code currently doesn't illustrate).

```
UPDATE m
 SET m.Monthly_Fee = c.Class_Price
 FROM dbo.Member AS m
 INNER JOIN dbo.Member_Account AS ma
 ON m.Member_Id = ma.Member_Id
 INNER JOIN dbo.Class AS c
 ON ma.Class_Id = c.Class_Id;
```

Of course, I wonder why you need to update the member table at all. Don't you send out the bills once a month? Can't you calculate this at runtime without even needing a `Monthly_Fee` column (perhaps storing the fees charged in a history table)? Why constantly update the member table with information you can get elsewhere?